# What version of syslog does Ubuntu 10.04.1 install default?

Tags: 10.04, versions, logging

I am planning a rsyslog deployment for my department using Ubuntu 10.04.1 - I cannot seem to find which version of syslog Ubuntu installs by default in the documentation, syslog-ng, sysklogd, old syslogd, or rsyslog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can go to **[packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)** to determine what versions there are (original, and current).
- Or you can check the **[manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.04/ubuntu-10.04.1-desktop-i386.manifest)** file of the desktop CD.
- Ubuntu 10.04.1 installs **rsyslog 4.2.0-2ubuntu8** by default.

Comment: Great answer.  I wasn't sure if the packages.ubuntu.com was the packages possible or the packages installed by default.  The manifest link did the trick.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For historic info, you can see all the releases of rsyslog packaged for Ubuntu at

- Universe (since 2007): http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rsyslog/
  starting with rsyslog_1.19.12-1.diff.gz       2007-12-04 13:05    11K
- Main (since 2009): http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/rsyslog/
  starting with rsyslog_4.2.0-2ubuntu5.1.diff.gz    2009-11-05 12:06    27K